# express: keep all DRY creating a mongoose connection module (using the new createConnection method)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here's my actual db connection module:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  conn = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'doto');

conn.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error! DB Connection failed.');
});

conn.once('open', function () {
  console.log('DB Connection open!');
});

module.exports = conn;
```

and there's a place where I use it

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  var conn = require('../lib/db_connection');

  conn.once('open', function () { // if i dont wrap with this, the page will not be rendered...
    conn.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
      res.render('list_collections', {
        title: 'Collections list',
        collections_names: names
      });
    });
  });
}
```

My question is: I really need to use conn.once every time? Any suggestion?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to use `conn.once` every time.  What specifically happens if you omit that?

Comment: Simply no "list_collections" view is rendered... when I send my request (typing localhost:3000/list_collections) I never get a response... (Sry again for my bad english.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `require` outside of your function so that the connection is opened when your application loads instead of waiting until the first request.

```
var conn = require('../lib/db_connection');
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  conn.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
    res.render('list_collections', {
      title: 'Collections list',
      collections_names: names
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Great it works! Thanks for your precious help, I really appreciate that!